# CORS with Amazon S3 and Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Rails App hosted on Heroku which is using CloudFront with assets hosted on S3.

It displays assets prefectly(although it took some wrestling).

My setup for Cloudfront:

```
Forward Headers: Whitelist
Whitelist Headers: Origin
Forward Query Strings: No
```

CORS setup for the S3 bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The JS that calls the image(coffee)

```
@mousemove (e) ->
  ctx = $("<canvas>").attr(
    width: @width
    height: @height
  )[0].getContext("2d")

  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, @width, @height)

  # This is because firefox doesn't support offset[X|Y]
  if(e.offsetX == undefined)
    xpos = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    ypos = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
  else
    xpos = e.offsetX;
    ypos = e.offsetY;

  e.rgb = ctx.getImageData(xpos, ypos, 1, 1).data
  return f.call this, e
```

This errors with:
`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

Curl request:

`curl -i -H "Origin: http://example.com/" http://randomness.cloudfront.net/franchisees/logos/000/000/006/icon/Screen_Shot_2014-08-06_at_15.21.14.png?1407334881`

```
  Response:
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: image/png
  Content-Length: 6888
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Wed, 06 Aug 2014 16:15:54 GMT
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
  Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Aug 2014 14:21:23 GMT
  ETag: "6f266467cf0a570526869bcf280da412"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Server: AmazonS3
  Age: 21
  Vary: Origin
  X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
  Via: 1.1 16d4ae36524b457e558b982004526450.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
  X-Amz-Cf-Id: 5Vm_eCn_lTOHEMzPEcmtCGYCUdOZ2r_9R4W6mEPTOPFUIJe0ilMP7g==

 *snip*
```

Its not a caching issue I've been using fresh images every time, although this request was on a cached version.

I know there are work arounds, but I would really like it to work this way.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where does the image come from (ie how do you load it) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that by default the browser won't check these cors headers - all images pulled in are dirty. For your cors headers to do anything you need to set the `crossorigin` attribute on the img, so that you get a [cors enabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

```html
<img src="blah" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

The crossorigin attribute can take the values `anonymous` or `use-credentials`. This is analogous to the `withCredentials` option when making cross domain ajax requests: by default cookies, http auth etc won't be sent. If you're creating the image in javascript then the corresponding property is `crossOrigin`.

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 support this, but released versions of Opera or Safari don't